# Getting cell reference via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel spreadsheet I want to insert the cell reference from **Cell A1** into **Cell B1** via VBA. 
In the end the spreadsheet should look like this:

```
     A       B
1           A1
2
3
4
```

**Cell B1** is filled by running a VBA that gets the cell reference from **Cell A1**. 
 I tried the following VBA but could not make it work (runtime error 1001):

```
Sub test()
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

What do I need to change in my VBA to solve my issue?

Comment: This works. I just tried this with a value "Hi!" in C1, and then the value "C1" written in cell A1. When run, the cell B1 duplicates the "Hi!" - what was it supposed to do?

Comment: Are you familiar with the INDIRECT function? It sounds like what you're trying to do

Comment: You could use the formula `=CELL("address",A1)` in `B1` and drag down.  This will give you the absolute address - `$A$1`.  Is that what you're after but using VBA?

Comment: Oh, I think you want `Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Address`

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Coop: That is exactly what I am looking for in VBA.

Comment: In that case - it's just what @jamheadart has commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full address of Cell A1 into Cell B1 you can use the function:

```
Sub AdressCell ()
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Address
End Sub
```

To get rid of the absolute references you can use:

```
Sub AdressCell ()
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Address(False, False)
End Sub
```

For only getting the Column you can use:

```
Sub AdressColumn ()
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Column
End Sub
```

For only getting the rows you can use:

```
Sub AdressRow ()
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Row
End Sub
```

Comment: If you place in a function you can use as a worksheetfunction as well - `Public Function GetMyAddress(Cell_Ref As Range) As String: GetMyAddress = Cell_Ref.Address: End Function`.

Comment: Good addition - `Address` is a very handy property I use often - not quite sure what OP's final goal is though

Comment: @jamheadart: Exactly, what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your answer.